# Saying aloud ‘a 100-year-old man’

Tags: grammaticality, numbers

Should it be just *‘a hundred-year-old man’* or *‘a one-hundred-year-old man’?*

Comment: Do you mean a [***hundred-year-old man**?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+hundred+year+old+man%22)

Comment: Oh, of course I do, sorry. :D

Comment: [Both forms occur,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+one+hundred+year+old%2Ca+hundred+year+old&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20hundred%20year%20old%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hundred%20year%20old%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20hundred%20year%20old%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hundred%20year%20old%3B%2Cc0) but note that ***an*** effectively means ***one***, so it's completely superfluous, and hence usually ***not*** included.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The "one" implied by "an" tells you how many men there are, not how many hundred years he lived.

Comment: Where would you say 'an'?

Comment: I also felt 'one' was superfluous, but I agree that 'a' tells the quantity of men and not that of hundreds.

Comment: I think that "hundred-year-old man" is less ambiguous. For example "a 20-year man" might mean someone who has served in the military for 20 years rather than someone who has lived 20 years.

Comment: If someone says "a hundred year man", I know that English is not his native language.  He is likely literally translating the way it is said in his own language.

Comment: It is less complicated to say 'a centenarian'.

Comment: @GEdgar: I never say so. It's just typing, and I wasn't concentrated on it.

Comment: Please note: my answer concerns **written texts**. Here we are with that old bugbear in this forum: written language **versus** spoken language.

Answer (score 1):

Google ngrams shows that both are used, although "a one hundred year" is not as common. Google ngrams can search phrases up to five words long, and "a one hundred year old man" has six words, so I removed "old man".

[image: ngram]

- [Book results for "a hundred year"](https://www.google.com/search?q="a%20hundred%20year"&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
- [Book results for "a one hundred year"](https://www.google.com/search?q="a%20one%20hundred%20year"&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

The results show that the phrases aren't being used in unexpected ways, so this data is as reliable as Google ngrams gets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, CJ Dennis!

Comment: Just so you know, even though in this case it doesn't make any difference, Google Books Ngram Viewer results are only reliable up to the year of 2000 (and I think from 1800). For some reason the setting defaults to 2008 as the upper limit, but that's a very recent change (as of 2020 or something), and it seems to be a mistake.

Comment: @Lambie The rule I've heard which makes sense is only use dashes to prevent ambiguity. Why would you need dashes here?

Comment: @Lambie The dashes are not de rigueur as the Google books results show. Without dashes ngrams is comparing apples to apples. Anyway, the OP asked about "**Saying aloud** ‘a 100-year-old man’". Do you have any evidence that dashes affect pronunciation? You're always welcome to post your own answer. Oh. I see you did. Oh. I see three users have taken issue with it and now you're just arguing with them. You are capable of giving good answers and I have on occasion upvoted them, but you can also be stubbornly wrong. I am now disengaging with you on this particular question.

Answer (score -1):

WRITTEN FORMS 
1) **a 100-year-old man = *using the number*.**

Other examples:

a 5-year-old boy
a 10-year-old cat
a 200-year-old tree

2) **a one-hundred-year-old man = *writing it out*.**

a five-year-old boy
a ten-year-old cat

One uses the number and the other is written out.

Examples from the Internet:

- My Life as a 10-Year-Old Boy
  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Life_as_a_10-Year-Old_Boy)
- A parent’s guide to the mind of a **five-year-old boy**

http://www.essentialkids.com.au/development-advice/advice/a-parents-guide-to-the-mind-of-a-fiveyearold-boy-20181012-h16ksfAustralian internet article]

SPOKEN based on the written form

They are both said the same way.

**However, there is a CAVEAT for the form below**:

**In spoken English**, if you hear "**a hundred year old man**" or "**a hundred bales of hay**", **those phrases are written as spoken**.

However, "a hundred-year-old man" does not pass the standard written English test (which is FINE: people speak the way they speak) and would not be used in the press, academia or other formal contexts. That said, "a hundred barrels of hay" would be used and is standard English.

**The reason this is confusing is this**:

When there is only **ONE of something**, we just use the **indefinite article a** unless there is doubt:

"I have a car". We don't generally say: I have one car.

Q: "Do you have **a car"**?
Ans: "Yes, I have **a car"**.
Q: "I mean do you have only one car"?
Ans: "Yes, **one car".**

Q: "Is there **a hundred-year-old man** sitting on a deck chair on your porch?"
Ans: "Yes, there is. In fact, there are two. There are **two one-hundred-year-old men sitting on the porch. They're twins**!"

a = one, in English. Though in speaking, this is not always clear. Native speakers just know that 'a' is one and when to clarify.

Summary:

Question, saying aloud: ‘a hundred-year-old man’ or ‘a one-hundred-year-old man’?
Answer: You can say what you have written. However, the grammar is tricky.

I have explained it above. The difference concerns the definite article 'a' and written English versus spoken English.

Comment: Are you saying it's only supposed to be read as *a one-hundred-year-old man*, and not *a hundred-year-old man*? https://www.nytimes.com/2011/07/25/us/25orleans.html says otherwise. (–1, misleading)

Comment: Written, read, same thing in this case. This is just misleading. You're saying this: it's written either as "100-year-old" or "one-hundred-year-old", and that is demonstrably false, since that's not the only way to write it (see the link above, for example).

Comment: -1 also for the same reason; the clarity of the answer could also be improved by using more complete sentences instead of terse "A: B" constructions.

Comment: Perhaps by writing you're also assuming a certain register. Except nowadays people express themselves in writing more often, and it's not a privilege, so writing can be thought of as a transcription of speech. I agree they're not the same thing, but I suppose the line between the two is getting blurrier and blurrier (to the point where I, for example, didn't even consider *writing* as different from *speech* in your post). And also to the point where people use e.g. air quotes, and *slash*, and *LOL*, and other such forms in speech.

Comment: @Lambie If you were more open to criticism I'd explain what I meant, but everything with you turns into a pointless debate and is a complete waste of time, so I'll let my vote stand without further comment.

Comment: 'The problem is in writing it out, you need the dashes' — you claim this, Lambie, and then you say: 'When you say a 100-year-old and a hundred year old, it is the same thing'.

Comment: No, I know how it should be written — I'm interested in spoken English.

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy Read what I added. It all depends on the register.

Comment: Thank you, Lambie!

Comment: *However, "a hundred-year-old man" does not pass the standard written English test* — I need to make sure that this is not only your opinion.